# Proper actions  on unitary  spheres  of  a  Hilbert  space

Tags: gt.geometric-topology

Free  group  action  of  spheres,  or  products  of  spheres  by  finite  groups  have  been  studied extensively in the  literature,  giving  in  many  cases  restrictions  to  the cohomological  properties  of  the  acting  group. Is  there  a characterization  of  groups  acting  properly and  discontinuously on the  unitary  sphere  of  a  Hilbert space?

Comment: Every torsion free discrete group $G$ acts properly and discontinuousy on the unit sphere of $L^2(G)$, no?

Comment: If you mean only topological actions, then this is the same of actions on Hilbert spaces, because the infinite-dimensional unitary sphere is diffeomorphic with the Hilbert space, see C. Bessaga, "Every infinite-dimensional Hilbert space is diffeomorphic with its unit sphere", Bull. Acad. Polon. Sci. Sér. Sci. Math. Astronom. Phys. 14 1966 27-31.

Comment: I am  Thinking  mainly  about  Isometric  actions. Thanks  for  the  comments. 

